# Why prints infinite value when I call it once?

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo, hook

it keeps calling the addName function infinitely -

- expo hooks SQLite .

```
//hook for displaying the names in the database
const [names, setNames] = useState([]);

console.log(names);
//inserts a name into the database, calls update if successful
const addName = () => {
  let newName = `${"empty"}-${"empty"}`;

  db.transaction((tx) => {
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Names(name) VALUES (?)", [newName], update());
  });
  //add the results of the database into the names hook
  const update = () => {
    console.log(db);
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        "SELECT name from Names",
        [],
        (tx, { rows }) => {
          setNames(() => {
            let retRA = [];
            rows._array.forEach((elem) => {
              retRA.unshift(elem.name);
            });
            return retRA;
          });
        },
        (tx, error) => {
          console.log("ERRORE-->SQLITE--->", error);
        }
      );
    });
  };
};
addName();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are calling `addName` in the main body of the component. Because `addName` updates the state this will lead to an infinite loop.

Try calling `addName` only when needed (after the user presses a button) or when the component mounts.